# random and different values when using the Array function “fill”

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const array = new Array(10);
array.fill('hi');
console.log(array);
```

Using `Array::fill` to populate a value on the whole array or part of the array.

I have a string generator function that generates a random string.

```js
const getString = () => Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
console.log(getString())
console.log(getString())
console.log(getString())
```

I want to fill the array with different values by executing the string generator function each time .

It cannot done by one line in `fill` , however, I found  a workaround leveraging the signature of `fill` : `arr.fill(value[, start = 0[, end = this.length]])`

```js
const getString = () => Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
const array = new Array(10);

for (var i=0; i < array.length;i++ ) {
  array.fill(getString(), i, i + 1);
}
console.log(array);
```

Does `fill` supports callbacks that can be executed each iteration to generate different values ?

If no, what is the alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

We can reach the same result in one line combining `map` and `fill` :

```
 array.fill().map(getString)
```

```js
const getString = () => Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');

const array = new Array(10);
console.log(array.fill().map(getString))
```